# Search center show custom column name

Tags: 2013, document-library, search, column

I created a document library with a few columns. One of them is a custom column named 'document title'. The search center seems to show the results as: document name, description and link. How to change the document name to show document title?

Comment: If you want to have custom columns show up in search center, you have to run a full crawl and create a managed property afterwards. After those steps, you should be able to change your display template to use "documen title" instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this tutorial which shows, how to customize search result 
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tothesharepoint/2013/09/06/how-to-display-values-from-custom-managed-properties-in-search-results-option-1/